# wrap content in a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to wrap content in a div but the problem is the html page is not editable so I am trying other way, using jQuery to wrap all the content in a `div` following is the `html` structure

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("hr").before("<div class=wrapElement>");
 $("#disqus_thread").before("</div>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hr>
<h4>Title Here</h4>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
```

**Problem** opening `div` is placed on correct position, but closing div is not on correct position, it should be above `div id="disqus_thread"` but its not there, how do I get it placed on this position?

jQuery version is 1.12.4

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to wrap the content from `hr` to the last `p`?

Comment: Yes to the last p, but I am targeting the last div because number of p may change as per the content

Comment: @SanjeevK what is the role of <p>&nbsp;</p>?

Comment: these p has text inside

Comment: @SanjeevK If you're going to use off site resources for your code examples, please try and make sure you keep the salient content the same.  You changed the div ID between JSFiddle and your question.  It's probably preferable to use a snippet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`nextUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) method to get all elements upto the div and use [`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) method to wrap them using a `div` element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("hr").nextUntil("#disqus_thread") // get elements from hr upto the previous element of #disqus_thread
       .wrapAll("<div class=wrapElement></div>"); // wrap all elements using div
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("hr").nextUntil("#disqus_thread").wrapAll("<div class=wrapElement></div>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hr>
<h4>Title Here</h4>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
```

Comment: @SanjeevK :  glad to help

Answer (score 1):

If you have a container you can use jQuery [wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/) method, easly :

```
$( "body" ).wrapInner( "<div class='wrapElement'></div>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, you can just use built-in jQuery functions:

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uhr4kuk6/5/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('hr').remove();
  $('h4').wrap('<div class="wrapElement">').prepend('<hr>');
  $('p').each(function() {
   var getContentWithTags = $(this).clone();
    $('.wrapElement').append(getContentWithTags);
    $(this).remove();
  })
});
```

```css
.wrapElement {
  background: red;
  padding-top: .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hr>
<h4>Title Here</h4>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your content is inside the body tag:

```
       var mainhtml=  $('body').find('*').not('#thread_content').html()
       $('#thread_content').html(mainhtml);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but unfortunately its not working, but answer provided by @PranavCBalan is working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<hr>
<h4>Title Here</h4>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>

$(document).ready(function() {
$("body").wrapInner("<div class=wrapElement></div>");
});
```