# Open div before container and close it after container

Tags: jquery

I want all my divs around my ps

I have tried this code but it obviously is not working code or even close to working.

```js
.prepend( $( '<div class="container">' ) );
.apppend( $( '</div>' ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>some text ......
</p>
```

Comment: Make your code runnable in a snippet

Comment: The issue is you are thinking you are appending html.  You are not.  `$('<div>')` parses the html and creates an Element, at which point there is no opening or closing tag.  It's an Element.  Likewise, `$('</div>')` jQuery has to figure out what the heck to do, because on its own thats not a complete tag.  So it also ends up created a complete Element as well.  You cannot chain append an open and close tag.  It doesn't work like that.

Comment: Maybe wrap is the word you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40625638/wrap-content-in-a-div-using-jquery